# How to add subtitle and footer on anychart 8

Tags: anychart

I am migrating a number of charts from anychart 6 (xml) to anychart 8 (javascript). I can't seem to find how to add a subtitle and a footer in anychart 8? These were available in anychart 6.

Comment: I imagine you would have to find a different way to do that. When people come up new versions of software, they have little *compassion* for backwards-compatibility, or dragging forward certain features (e.g: **subtitles & footers**).

I would check the **[documentation](https://api.anychart.com/8.0.1/anychart)**. If it's not there, it's not there! Go on their GitHub page and see if other people are complaining, or open a pull-request with the ported functionality. Probably it wasn't something they cared to push into version 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These features are available in the latest version too. Please take a look at the current title:
https://docs.anychart.com/Common_Settings/Title
You can use the HTML tags, e.g.

```
title.useHtml(true);
title.text(
  "Sales Performance"+
  "<br><a style=\"color:#0000FF; font-size: 10px;\">"+
  "according to annual report</a>"
);
```

It will create the subtitle:
https://playground.anychart.com/docs/8.0.1/samples/CS_Titles_06-plain
Also, this example (it is related to statistics in common, but shows the idea): https://playground.anychart.com/docs/8.0.1/samples/CS_Statistics_05-plain

As for the footer, it can be done with the chart label:
https://docs.anychart.com/Common_Settings/Chart_Labels
You can define the label position, text content and other settings. I made the simple example to illustrate the point: https://jsfiddle.net/sye89q5z/